# How to use common paths in Eclipse Application and the generated JAR?

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin, and most of the time I run as "Eclipse Application", but sometimes I also export as a JAR.

I have two source folders, "src/" and "icons/". The problem is that when I run as "Eclipse Application" the path to the Icons are "icons/com/...", while when I generate the JAR the paths become "/com/...".

I would like a common path that will work whether I generate a JAR or run as an Eclipse Application. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't specify `icons` as a source folder just leave it as a plain folder. Do include it in the `build.properties` so that it is included in the built plug-in.

Use the `FileLocator` class to locate objects in plug-ins.

For images you can use something like:

```java
String path = "icons/xxxxxx.jpg";  // TODO your path to the image

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);

ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
```

Note that the URL from `FileLocator.find` is only suitable for use by Eclipse APIs. You can convert it to a more normal URL using:

```java
URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```